# How to use -extends in Erlang R17

Tags: erlang, extends

The -extends feature was remove in recent Erlang version

I have some legacy modules which made heavy use of -extends

How to get it work in R17?

Answer (score 2):

It was an experimental feature that has been removed in R17.

So if you really have to go with R17, you will have to add in all child module a definition of each inherited function:

```
inherited_function (Param) -> parent:inherited(Param).
```

I wrote a naive code that insert the needed functions and export directly in the existing code. It need to work in the src directory with access to the ebin directory (call Module:module_info(exports)) - so i would use it on a copy of the project :o). It make some assumption on the extend directive (no blank characters) and does not split the added export directive in several lines, which might be a problem, but it works on my example

example of code to modify:
root module

```
-module (gd_father).

-export([gdf1/0,gdf2/1,gdf2/2]).

gdf1() -> gd_father.

gdf2(P) -> {gd_father,P}.

gdf2(P1,P2) when is_list(P2) -> [gd_father,P1|P2];
gdf2(P1,P2) -> [gd_father,P1,P2].
```

child level 1

```
-module (father).

-extends(gd_father).

-export([ft1/1,ft2/0]).

-export([gdf2/1]).

ft1(X) -> {father,X}.

ft2() -> father.

gdf2(P1) -> {ovl_father,P1}.
```

children level 2

```
-module (child1).

-extends(father).

-export ([cd1/0]).

-export ([ft1/1]).

cd1() -> child1.

ft1(X) -> {ovl_child1,X}.
```

.

```
-module (child2).

-extends(father).

-export ([cd2/0]).

-export ([ft2/0,gdf1/0]).

cd2() -> child2.

ft2() -> ovl_child2.

gdf1() -> ovl_child2.
```

a test module to verify it works (compilation with R17 gives no error in case of -extend directive usage!)

```
-module (test).

-export([t/0]).

t() ->
    gd_father = gd_father:gdf1(),
    {gd_father,3} = gd_father:gdf2(3),
    [gd_father,1,2] = gd_father:gdf2(1,2),
    [gd_father,1,2,3] = gd_father:gdf2(1,[2,3]),

    {father,4} = father:ft1(4),
    father = father:ft2(),
    {ovl_father,5} = father:gdf2(5),
    [gd_father,1,2] = father:gdf2(1,2),
    gd_father = father:gdf1(),
    [gd_father,1,2,3] = father:gdf2(1,[2,3]),

    child1 = child1:cd1(),
    {ovl_child1,test} = child1:ft1(test),
    father = child1:ft2(),
    {ovl_father,5} = child1:gdf2(5),
    [gd_father,1,2] = child1:gdf2(1,2),
    gd_father = child1:gdf1(),
    [gd_father,1,2,3] = child1:gdf2(1,[2,3]),

    child2 = child2:cd2(),
    ovl_child2 = child2:ft2(),
    ovl_child2 = child2:gdf1(),
    {father,4} = child2:ft1(4),
    {ovl_father,5} = child2:gdf2(5),
    [gd_father,1,2] = child2:gdf2(1,2),
    [gd_father,1,2,3] = child2:gdf2(1,[2,3]),

    ok.
```

transform module:

```
-module (transform).

-export([transform_dir/0,transform_file/1]).


transform_dir() ->
    {ok,AllFiles} = file:list_dir("."),
    Files = [list_to_atom(lists:sublist(X,length(X)-4)) || X <- AllFiles, is_src(lists:reverse(X))],
    transform_file(Files).

transform_file([]) -> ok;
transform_file([H|Q]) ->
    {_,_,Add,Father,Lines} = transform_file(H),
    mod_file(H,Add,Father,Lines),
    transform_file(Q);
transform_file(Name) ->
    FileName = atom_to_list(Name) ++ ".erl",
    {ok,Bin} = file:read_file(FileName),
    List = binary_to_list(Bin),
    Lines = string:tokens(List,"\n"),
    Father = to_atom([string:strip(X) || X <- Lines, is_extend(X)]),
    OrExp = Name:module_info(exports),
    case Father of
        none -> {OrExp,OrExp,[],none,[]};
        Father ->   {_,Fa_Tot,_,_,_} = transform_file(Father),
                Or = lists:usort(OrExp),
                Tot = lists:usort(Fa_Tot ++ OrExp),
                Add = lists:usort(lists:subtract(Tot,Or)),
                {Or,Tot,Add,Father,Lines}
    end.

is_extend([$-,$e,$x,$t,$e,$n,$d,$s|_]) -> true;
is_extend(_) -> false.

is_src([$l,$r,$e,$.|_]) -> true;
is_src(_) -> false.

to_atom([]) -> none;
to_atom([L]) ->
    list_to_atom(tl(lists:takewhile(fun(X) -> X =/= $) end , lists:dropwhile(fun(X) -> X =/= $( end,L)))).

mod_file(_,[],_,_) -> ok;
mod_file(F,L,Father,Lines) ->
    Export = lists:flatten(["\n%Replace expends directive by export\n-export([",
              tl(lists:flatten([", " ++ atom_to_list(X) ++ "/" ++ integer_to_list(N) || {X,N} <- L])),
              "]).\n"]), 
    Def = lists:flatten(["\n\n%Insert relay functions to replace the expends directive\n" |[add_def(X,Father) || X <- L]]),
    NewLines = insert(Lines,Export,Def,[]),
    file:write_file(atom_to_list(F)++".erl",NewLines,[write]).

insert([],_,Def,R) -> lists:reverse([Def|R]);
insert([H|Q],Export,Def,R) ->
    Line = case is_extend(H) of
        true -> Export;
        false -> H
    end,
    insert(Q,Export,Def,[Line|R]).

add_def({N,A},F) -> 
    Args = args(A,[]),
    atom_to_list(N) ++ Args ++ " -> " ++ atom_to_list(F) ++ ":" ++ atom_to_list(N) ++ Args ++ ".\n".

args(0,[]) -> "()";
args(0,R) -> "(" ++ lists:reverse(tl(R)) ++ ")";
args(A,R) -> args(A-1,[$,,A-1+$A,$P|R]).
```

result on child level 2, after compilation of all modules, the test is ok:

```
-module (child1).

%Replace expends directive by export
-export([ ft2/0, gdf1/0, gdf2/1, gdf2/2]).
-export ([cd1/0]).

-export ([ft1/1]).

cd1() -> child1.

ft1(X) -> {ovl_child1,X}.

%Insert relay functions to replace the expends directive
ft2() -> father:ft2().
gdf1() -> father:gdf1().
gdf2(PA) -> father:gdf2(PA).
gdf2(PB,PA) -> father:gdf2(PB,PA).
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [parse transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2522574/9204) which inserts parent module's name before every function call which is 1) non-qualified; 2) doesn't refer to a function in the current module; 3) doesn't refer to a built-in function.

Shouldn't be too difficult but I would still only do this if you have really heavy use of `extends`, as it makes the code less understandable and might require maintenance if the abstract format changes.

Comment: I will have a deeper look at the parse transform, but I don't understand how this can work without looking recursively into the parent definition to find all the unmodified inherited functions.

Comment: @Pascal Oops, didn't take into account that the parent can itself extend another module. So this is probably not workable.